# Remote Access ESXI,what should i do for remotely access it at home?

Tags: vmware-esxi

what should i do for remotely access it at home?
Im trying to learn a few things about Virtualiztion. Ive been able to install ESXI on a host at office and can access it through vSphere client locally

Comment: Don't repost closed question. Fix the reasons for it being closed. In this case, you should probably clarify a lot about your network.

Comment: In addition to that, probably SF was not the right place to ask. Try asking on SuperUser, and yes, don't forget to elaborate the question further.